# Android SharedPreferences is not saving after re-opening the application

Tags: android

I am trying to add a function named `removeCard`, this function receives an array of strings. This array length is 48 and the strings inside this array contains a name of a card, i.e *prince* or *knight*. If a `String` inside this array is `null` it means there is no more card to delete (the game contains 48 cards but maybe I want to delete just 2 of them).

All my cards are saved in `SharedPreferences` with the key `key1`. This function is supposed to remove from the key all the cards inside the array (if someone accidentally added the prince but he didn't unlock it yet).

However, this function works fine and when I return to the `main3.class` intent it shows the cards inside the array were removed from the `SharedPreferences` key but when I close the application and re-open it, they remain like they never were removed.

Here is my code:

```
public static void removeCard(String[] s) {
    Set<String> used;
    used = prefs.getStringSet("key1", null);

    for (String card : s) {
        if (card != null)
            used.remove(card);
        else 
            break;
    }

    editor.putStringSet("key1", used);
    editor.commit();
    Intent k = new Intent(cont, main3.class);
    cont.startActivity(k);
}
```

Also, the `array` contains the cards to remove is being created when you click on a `ListView` item (each item is a card). `result[position]` is the card name and `cards` is the `array` contains values to remove:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (position == 0) { // back button pressed
        main2.removeCard(cards);                    
        main2.cont.finish(); // close main2 activity
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, result[position] + " Picked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Toast the card you picked
        if (!Arrays.asList(cards).contains(result[position])) { // if card is not already in array, add it.
            cards[count] = result[position];
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I'm getting the editor of the `SharedPreferences`.

```
public static SharedPreferences prefs;
public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    cont = this;
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(main2.this, mDrawableName, mDrawableImg, n));
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
    editor = prefs.edit();
}
```

And also, to display the cards you have from the other activity I used:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> cards = pref.getStringSet("key1", null);
tv1.setText("Available cards: " + cards);
```

Comment: please add how are you getting the sharedPreferences and the editor

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga Sure, in the first activity where the function exists?

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga Added my friend.

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 check your editor.commit() executed successfully by boolean success = editor.commit(); maybe there is something wrong there

Comment: @Pooya returned true :(

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 is there a reason that you declare pref as static?

Comment: @Pooya Yes, I am using it inside the method and it is static, if I don't declare pref as static I cannot use it. and if I don't declare the method as static, it causes me some other problems.